# DRF django-rest-framework-simplejwt JWTAuthentication not working

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

Ideally using `django-rest-framework-simplejwt` and the authentication class `JWTAuthentication`, the API should give `403` when I pass the token incorrectly.

Instead, when I am making my API request it is executing successfully even without the Authentication token.

This is a dummy API, my concern is the Authentication should work.

My code looks like this:

```
class ViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = get_user_model().objects.all()
    serializer_class = SomeSerializer
    http_method_names = ("post", "patch")
    authentication_classes = (JWTAuthentication,)
```

When I debug I see that it is executing JWTAuthentication, which in turn returns None.
Which is expected since I am not passing the Token in the header.

```
    def authenticate(self, request):
        header = self.get_header(request)
        if header is None:
            return None
```

Now I think the View should give Permission Denied, which is not happening.

Not able to understand what is missing here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you pass incorrect token, it'll return 401 status response.
But if you don't put authorization header on your request, django will not return 401 response and behave with request as **AnonymousUser** request.
If you want only authenticated users have access to your **ViewSet**, you should put `permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated,]` in your **ViewSet**.
**IsAuthenticated** permission class can be imported from *rest_framework.permissions*